# How do I organize related tables in a database

Tags: database, database-design, join, relational-database

I have the following situation:

```
table User (id, name)
table Belonging (id, name, color)
table UserBelonging (id, user_id, belonging_id)
```

Now, `UserBelonging` is my join table that connects `User` and his `Belonging`.

The problem arises when I want to pull out all belongings of a certain `User`, that are red.

I see two ways to do that:

1. Get all `UserBelonging` for a certain user, then loop through them and check which are red
2. Put an extra column like that: `UserBelonging (id, user_id, belonging_id, color)` and then query in the same table.

Both methods seem ugly to me. Is there anyone with experience in database tables that could tell me which way is better and why or possibly give me a better solution?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The join table should **only** contain `user_id` and `belonging_id`, with either a composite ID of `(user_id, belonging_id)` or an autoincrement `id` column.

That rules out #2.

---

Now, you could use strategy #1, or you could filter out non-red belongings in the `select` statement.

```
SELECT b.id, b.name, b.color
FROM UserBelonging ub
LEFT JOIN Belonging b
ON ub.belonging_id = b.id
WHERE ub.user_id = 123456789
AND b.color = 'red'
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT B.* FROM User U
INNER JOIN UserBelonging UB on UB.UserId=U.Id
INNER JOIN Belonging B on B.Id = UB.BelongingId
Where B.Color = 'red' AND U.Name='Sam'
```

I think a join like this will do what you want.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily use 1 JOIN and A WHERE statement with your color condition and user_id. Joins are one of the most common operations when discussing about relational-databases.
Check [W3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp) for some basic examples.

Answer (score 0):

It's generally best not to use loops in databases. In SQL Server I would do it like this (but I don't know if it's applicable to your DB)

```
    Select User.Name, Belonging.name, Belonging.color from User inner join UserBelonging 
    on User.id =     UserBelonging.user_id inner join Belonging 
    on UserBelonging.belonging_id = Belonging.id 
    where Belonging.color = 'red' and User.name = 'put the name here'
```

regards

Tim